# Select PrimeNg multiselect option on button click, Angular

Tags: angular, primeng, multi-select

I am using `primeng multiselect` for multi-select dropdown with search functionality.
Everything is working fine in normal scenario, but now i have buttons which are associated with each options. On the click of the button i want to select respective option from the select list and it should update the label as well.

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <p-multiSelect [options]="bins" defaultLabel="Select Bins" [(ngModel)]="selectedBins" (onChange)="binSelect($event)"></p-multiSelect>
    <p>Selected Bins: {{selectedBins}}</p>
</div>
<button (click)="clicked('bin1')">Bin 1</button>
<button (click)="clicked('bin2')">Bin 2</button>
```

**Component**

```
interface ObjBinMultiSelect {
  name: string,
  code: string
}

export class Test implements OnInit{

  bins: SelectItem[];
  selectedBins: ObjBinMultiSelect[] = [];

  //Pushing the data on service call success using forEach
  //below list is just for reference

  bins.push({ label: "bin1", value: "bin1" });
  bins.push({ label: "bin2", value: "bin2" });

  clicked(val) {
      this.selectedBins.push(val);
  }
}
```

On the `clicked` function i am able to check the checkbox of respected value but not able to update the labels. Also i am not sure whether pushing the value is the proper way or not. how to achieve this and also whether this is a proper way or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is behaving weird. Seems like there is some issue with the core implementation of custom form field. Investigation found that `ngModel` value reference change only updating the value primeng multiselect. As a workaround you can consider using below. If I get more time I'll try to find what exactly wrong with primeng multiselect implementation.

```
clicked(val) {
    let oldSelected = [...this.selectedBins];
    // Before pushing value, make sure its unique.
    oldSelected.push(val);
    this.selectedBins = oldSelected
}
```

[**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-m1yn9q?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks Pankaj...this works for me now...just need to pop out the value if it is already selected and clicked again.

Comment: That's what my comment in the function ;) I'd say check if value exist before pushing it to collection